# RESTEasy client API file upload to python/Flask

Tags: java, python, flask, resteasy

I'm trying to upload a file using RESTEasy client api to a python Flask REST service but I'm ending up with a HTTP 400 Bad Request response.

The Java client:

```
MultipartFormDataOutput mpfdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
mpfdo.addFormData("video", new FileInputStream(new File('file')), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("localhost:5000").path("/video/detect");
Response r = target.request().post(Entity.entity(mpfdo, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
```

The python service:

```
@app.route('/video/detect', methods=["POST"])
def VideoDetectFrame():
   f = request.files['video']
   #returns 400 response
```

The data seems to be in `request.form` but not in `request.files` like it should. It works as expected when sending a file using Postman.

Comment: Try this link, i think it will be a help for you. https://dzone.com/articles/restful-web-services-with-python-flask

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga Thx. But I think the problem lies in the Java part. When using Postman it works and I just tried sending a file both through python's requests.session() and curl also with success.